no gradle tool in "Tool Windows" in Android Studio
I have flutter project. I use Android studio.
I have installed gradle plugin but I don't see gradle bar, or even in "View" -> "Tool Windows" there is no gradle. Looks like the gradle is not working or can't detect my project
I opened build.gradle file, I don't see promt "Sync now".
I looked in menu "File" -> "Sync project with Gradle Files"
I tried to find other mentions in menu

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You need to edit your question and add the additional info there.

If you want to find gradle tool under View tab, you should open only the "android" folder with Android Studio IDE.
If you open the whole Flutter project with Android Studio, you wil not find gradle option under the view tab.

I found decision. I had open my project folder. What is need to do is to open folder of your android app, where is your build.gradle located.(File->Open and choose destination yo your project "/android". "Ok") And also delete "build" folder. after it everything started working, "Sync project with gradle" appears and "Gradle" tab
